# Can't connect with Oracle sqldeveloper or sqlplus

Tags: oracle, connection, database-connection, oracle-sqldeveloper

Right now I've just installed Oracle on Windows, so far I've successfully logged in with sys and system users via sqlplus and the enterprise manager GUI and created a new user. Now, I'm able to log in with this new user through the enterprise manger web interface but when I try to log in with sqlplus or with sqldeveloepr I get the error "ERROR: ORA-01017: invalid username/password; logon denied".

I've re-entered the password several times making sure not to make mistakes but yet again, I can't login. I can only connect with this user via enterprise manager web gui.

Any ideas why this would happen? :(

[Here is the user logged into web EM](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Uzgqd.png)

[Error in sqldeveloper](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ul5d4.png). I get the same error in sqlplus console, what I find strange is that if I use either system or sys user, it does connect successfully. So is my newly created user missing a role or privilege?

In the case of sqldeveloper I've tried both "localhost" and "127.0.0.1" as host and I'm getting the same result.

Comment: What is your database version up to 4 decimal places?

Comment: Which version of Oracle are you using? I would suspect password case sensitivity rules as a starting point. For the password, did you try to use all in UPPER CASE as a troubleshooting manner?

Comment: Is it possible, that you forgot to commit the changes? Therefore you can see the user only in the open session. Another idea - what priviliges has this new user? grant connect, create session, imp_full_database to <user>; could solve the problem.

Comment: I'm using Oracle 12c, as for the password since I'm using it for local tests/development I used all lowercase password without numeric or special characters. Don't know if this may have something to do with the error though :(

Comment: @mcane I've logged out and log back in with the new user through the web gui and it works fine, it's just with sqlplus and sqldeveloper that I'm having isssues :( I'll try granting connect and create session once I get home, I'm at work right now :) Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you don't have enough privileges. Try this:

```
grant connect, create session to <user>;
```

Comment: I'll try granting these privileges and see if it works.

Comment: This did not work :( I'm still getting "ERROR: ORA-01017: invalid username/password; logon denied"

Answer (score 0):

Well.. it seems that it's working now, at least with sqldeveloper. Apparently I needed to use the Service Name and not the SID when trying to connect, at least that's what I tried based on the answer by "thatjeffsmith" here:  [ora-12505 error while connecting via SQL Developer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25705602/ora-12505-error-while-connecting-via-sql-developer)

I suppose that granting connect and create session also helped.

Also on the service name I typed the container name? for the pluggable database which in my case is "**p**oraclepredb" the container being "oraclepredb". Now I'm able to connect with sqldeveloper. Still not sure on how connect with sqlplus though, since I can't "tell" which SID/Service it's using. Any ideas on that?

**UPDATE:** I was finally able to log in with sqlplus using the syntax:

```
sqlplus <user>/<password>@<host>:<port>/<database>
```

in my case for "database" i typed the name of my pluggable database.

The same can be done when sqlplus asks for the username, typing:

```
<user>/<password>@<host>:<port>/<database>
```

the downside on this is that the password is visible whenever I log in.

Comment: In linux: 
    ORACLE_SID=<your sid>
    export ORACLE_SID
    echo $ORACLE_SID

Comment: Above are three commands. Similar should be for SERVICE_NAME. If you think that grant privileges helped, you can an up-vote the answer.