# ORA-12505, TNS:listener does not currently know of SID given in connect descriptor?

Tags: java, oracle

When i try to connect to oracle through SQL Developer or my java application i get below error, though i am able to connect
from SQL PLUS (command line tool)

```
    Listener refused the connection with the following error :

    ORA-12505, TNS:listener does not currently know 
    of SID given in connect descriptor
```

I face this problem whenever i do system restart. Though 1 out of 10 time after system restart , i am able to connect successfully.

I can see all of the oracle services including **`OracleOraDb11g_home1TNSListener`** are up under services section. Just for information
my SID name is **`orcl`**

After going thru Luke answer at [ORA-12505, TNS:listener does not currently know of SID given in connect descriptor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18192521/ora-12505-tnslistener-does-not-currently-know-of-sid-given-in-connect-descript)
looks like at the time of restart oracle database gets started earlier than **`OracleOraDb11g_home1TNSListener`**. so its not able
to register with listener.

I think solution should be make listener up first then start the database. **How can i configure to start database after some time lag after reboot ?**

Comment: The database should attempt to register periodically; I'd expect it to do that within about a minute of the listener coming up, if the DB started first. Does it appear eventually, or if you explicitly do `alter system register` as SYS from SQL*Plus? If not does your IP address change on reboot, and is the `local_listener` init parameter set? (Erm, except the listener is on localhost from another comment, so it probably isn't an IP issue...)

Comment: Almost it happens every time  when i restart the system. Also i don't explicitly register the db with listenet(it should happen automatically on reboot. And yes sometimes it happens but sometime it does not). I pasted the result of "lsnrctl status" under comments ofLalit answer. Can you make out something out of it ?

Comment: You asked "does your IP address change on reboot ?" Probably yes. But how does it impact? You also asked "is the local_listener init parameter set ?" i am not sure where to check this and whats the importance of it ?

Comment: @emily - it probably doesn't matter, since your listener is on localhost. `show parameters listener` would tell you if that is set, but there would have to be a discrepancy amd something odd for it to matter. If it isn't set it defaults to localhost:1521, which is what your listener is on anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I face this problem whenever i do system restart. Though 1 out of 10 time after system restart , i am able to connect successfully.

The possible reason would be that the `SERVICES` are not up after the system restart. The way to check it, depends on the `operating system`.

For example, in `Windows OS` you could go to `services.msc` and see whether the TNS service is up and running.

To check whether listener is up or not, and whether the DB is registered, check `lsnrctl status`. Also, remember, the `listener` needs sometime after your system restart. The same applies after any changes to the listener, you must wait for sometime.

Comment: @ lalit kumar as i said in my post "I can see all of the oracle services including OracleOraDb11g_home1TNSListener are up under services section". So i think somehow db is not registered with listener. I did ran "lsnrctl status". But which parameter tells that DB is registered with listener or not?

Comment: Post the results of lsnrctl status. And did you try lsnrctl stop and start?

Comment: I don't see any service registered...there are no instances identified.