# How to confiure the JDBC URL with service name when use C3P0 CONNECT oracle database?

Tags: c3p0

I have meet one issue:

There is one database,it could be connected by sqldeveloper tools

[image]

But I want to use c3p0 to connect the database with the jdbcurl:

jdbc:oracle:thin:@2.2.6.11:2709:hl.webtest.com

get these error:
WARN - com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool$AcquireTask@55854763 -- Acquisition Attempt Failed!!! Clearing pending acquires. While trying to acquire a needed new resource, we failed to succeed more than the maximum number of allowed acquisition attempts (5). Last acquisition attempt exception: 
java.sql.SQLException: Listener refused the connection with the following error:
**ORA-12505, TNS:listener does not currently know of SID given in connect descriptor**

```
at oracle.jdbc.driver.SQLStateMapping.newSQLException(SQLStateMapping.java:70)
```

why C3p0 throw the error? It seemed that the jdbcurl is wrong, what is correct jdbcurl  with the Service Name?

Comment: Please see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18192521/ora-12505-tnslistener-does-not-currently-know-of-sid-given-in-connect-descript maybe try replacing the last ':' with a '/'?

Comment: Thank you ,it work now with ' /'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
jdbc:oracle:thin:@//2.2.6.11:2709/hl.webtest.com
```

it is use service_name, not the SID

 You need the `//` and the `/`