# Error in Creating New Database connection in Sql Developer

Tags: sql, oracle, database-connection

I'm getting following error while creating new database

myusername/mypassword, 
Hostname - localhost,
Port - 1521,
SID - XE

> Status : Failure -Test failed: Listener refused the connection with
>   the following error: ORA-12505, TNS:listener does not currently know
>   of SID given in connect descriptor

Comment: Can you show how you are creating the database?

Comment: check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18192521/ora-12505-tnslistener-does-not-currently-know-of-sid-given-in-connect-descript and this http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14219/net12500.htm

Comment: have you taken a look at http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14219/net12500.htm ? go to 12505 and try what it says there

Answer (score 0):

try this. source from [docs.oracle](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14219/net12500.htm)

```
ORA-12505: TNS:listener does not currently know of SID given in connect descriptor
 Cause: 
The listener received a request to establish a connection to a database or other service. The connect descriptor received by the listener specified a SID for an instance (usually a database instance) that either has not yet dynamically registered with the listener or has not been statically configured for the listener. This may be a temporary condition such as after the listener has started, but before the database instance has registered with the listener.
Action: 
- Wait a moment and try to connect a second time.

- Check which instances are currently known by the listener by executing: lsnrctl services <listener name>

- Check that the SID parameter in the connect descriptor specifies an instance known by the listener.

- Check for an event in the listener.log file.
```