# What is OS authentication for a database?

Tags: database, oracle-sqldeveloper

While trying to connect to database facing some error like 
"ORA-12505, TNS:listener does not currently know of SID given in connect descriptor"

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ORA-12505, TNS:listener does not currently know of SID given in connect descriptor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18192521/ora-12505-tnslistener-does-not-currently-know-of-sid-given-in-connect-descript)

Comment: OS Authentication for a database means the database is going to trust your operating system to make sure you are who you say you are, so if you are JDSMITH on windows xyz, then there will be a JDSMITH user in the database, that you will access from your machine/network as long as you're logged in as JDSMITH https://oracle-base.com/articles/misc/os-authentication