# ORA-12505, TNS:listener does not currently know of SID given in connect descriptor on server

Tags: java, jdbc, server, oracle12c, jdbc-odbc

I am getting **ORA-12505** whenever trying to create a connection when pc is on the server.

If I disconnect pc from the server then connection creating. but when I connect pc to the server then I am getting an error **ORA-12505**

> Status:: Failure -Test failed: Listener refused the connection with
>   the following error: ORA-12505, TNS:listener does not currently know
>   of SID given in connect descriptor"

and I have not changed in **listener.ora** file and **tnsnames.ora**.

please help me .....

[Error PrtScr](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dxx0Z.png)

Comment: Check if listener can be resolved by running tnsping command ? If not, then you need to define entry in tnsnames.ora ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ORA-12505, TNS:listener does not currently know of SID given in connect descriptor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18192521/ora-12505-tnslistener-does-not-currently-know-of-sid-given-in-connect-descript)

Answer (score 1):

In your connection string change from **SID="abc"** to **SERVICE_NAME="abc**".

Resolved this by installing Oracle SQL Developer on server, and I got the same error message "*ORA-12505: TNS:listener does not currently know of SID given in connect descriptor*", if you use SID in the connection properties.

Change to **SERVICE_NAME** in your connection string, and you should be able to successfully connect to the database