# Getting Error ORA-12505, TNS:listener does not currently know of SID given in connect descriptor

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, oracle-sqldeveloper, sqlplus

After installation of oracle 11g SQL Developer and Database control URL both work very nice
but when i restart my machine non of this works i tried it 3 times by installing oracle again and again but every time its same result.

SQL Developer gives error:

> **"ORA-12505, TNS:listener does not currently know of SID given in connect descriptor"**

I have checked LISTENER status in cmd line but it is showing up over there and i am able to fire query there also. I also checked:

- USERNAME,
- PASSWORD,
- ROLE,
- SID,
- HOSTNAME,
- PORT(SID, HOSTNAME, PORT in tnsnames.ora file)

...everything is perfectly entered working fine after installation and before restart but not after restart and when trying to access Database control URL,

> **404 Not Found error**

error comes.

Is there anybody who know about it. Please help me out.

Comment: Did you check that the services are actually running? can you do a tnsping from the command line?

Comment: thanks  i just checked Listener is really working.  is there any other possibility for this errors?

Comment: Make sure you connect using the SERVICE_NAME - not the SID. Like user/pass@hostname:1521/SERVICE_NAME (no colon - that means SID)

Comment: Did you try : "Open Services, and start OracleServiceXE, after that try to connect." and also here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18192521/ora-12505-tnslistener-does-not-currently-know-of-sid-given-in-connect-descript you have a lots o advice's

Comment: What operating system?  Windows? Linux?  Please add the appropriate tag for the operating system (and you can remove the oracle-sqldeveloper tag since results are the same for it and database control)

Comment: Dear Old Programmer i checked Listener with the use of wrong string in cmd i  checked with the string -----sqlplus system/system-password as sysdba -----.which connect direct to database without listener. Now i checked with string ---- sqlplus system/system-password@XE----   which shows error   ( ORA-12514: TNS:listener does not currently know of service requested in connect
descriptor  )      i think this msg shows that listener is not working.                                       do you have any idea how to solve it?

Comment: Dear Mark OS is windows 10 64 bit

Comment: Dear Bjarte its not working.

Comment: Dear VBokšić your given link did help me. thanks a lot. Problem solved.

Answer (score 2):

by below process my problem got solved.

1. Opened cmd in admin mode.
2. wrote **sqlplus system/password as sysdba** and pressed enter.
3. wrote **alter system set local_listener = '(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=localhost)(PORT=1521))' scope = both;** and pressed enter.

problem got solved.

Answer (score 0):

Any one of the below might suit you.

1. Hope you were using windows 10 and oracle 11gXE combo 
   in that case either use windows 7 with 11g or opt for 18C xe with windows 10
2. More than one version of oracle xe was installed in the same machine now or earlier ? 
   in that case install from new windows-admin-user with "run as administrator" on the setup file

--from Personal experience

Comment: Dear Nizamudeen i first formatted  my pc after that i have installed oracle with "run as administrator" option.