# I cannot find my SID (ORA-12505 error in SQLdeveloper)

Tags: oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

I am studying Spring Web project with STS, SQLdeveloper, 11g expression edition. I am a beginner with Web programming and I cannot access my database because of `ORA-12505 error`. I cannot move forward because of this error and I'd appreciate it if someone helped me.

**The problem is:**

[image]

**my state is...**

**[lsnrctl services]**
[image]

**[listener.ora]**

```
SID_LIST_LISTENER =
  (SID_LIST =
    (SID_DESC =
      (SID_NAME = PLSExtProc)
      (ORACLE_HOME = C:\oraclexe\app\oracle\product\11.2.0\server)
      (PROGRAM = extproc)
    )
    (SID_DESC =
      (SID_NAME = CLRExtProc)
      (GLOBAL_DBNAME = XE)
      (ORACLE_HOME = C:\oraclexe\app\oracle\product\11.2.0\server)
      (PROGRAM = extproc)
      (SID_NAME = XE)
    )
  )

LISTENER =
  (DESCRIPTION_LIST =
    (DESCRIPTION =
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = IPC)(KEY = EXTPROC1521))
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = DESKTOP******)(PORT = 1521))
    )
  )

DEFAULT_SERVICE_LISTENER = (XE)

**[tnsnames.ora]** 

XE =
  (DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = DESKTOP-8E8LG2B)(PORT = 1521))
    (CONNECT_DATA =
      (SERVER = DEDICATED)
      (SERVICE_NAME = XE)
    )
  )


EXTPROC_CONNECTION_DATA =
  (DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS_LIST =
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = IPC)(KEY = EXTPROC1))
    )
    (CONNECT_DATA =
      (SID = PLSExtProc)
      (PRESENTATION = RO)
    )
  )

ORACLR_CONNECTION_DATA = 
  (DESCRIPTION = 
    (ADDRESS_LIST = 
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = IPC)(KEY = EXTPROC1)) 
    ) 
    (CONNECT_DATA = 
      (SID = CLRExtProc) 
      (PRESENTATION = RO) 
    ) 
  )
```

[image]

Comment: Perhaps [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18192521/ora-12505-tnslistener-does-not-currently-know-of-sid-given-in-connect-descript/46848944) helps.

Comment: Put "XE" into "Service name" instead of into "SID" (it is a line below "SID").

Comment: Which line? Can you write the text for me..?

Comment: are you sure your db is running? your listener log indicates it's not