# EKS has issue connecting Oracle

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, amazon-eks

I have Azure devops pipeline which deploys in Amazon k8s, the pipeline is working very fine and with no issue and it is deploying in k8s.

Mine is a Spring Boot application, when starting the application it makes a connection to Oracle db. And I get the below error.

```
[nio-8203-exec-3] com.zaxxer.hikari.util.DriverDataSource  : Registered driver with driverClassName=oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver was not found, trying direct instantiation.

Caused by: oracle.net.ns.NetException: Listener refused the connection with the following error:
ORA-12505, TNS:listener does not currently know of SID given in connect descripto
```

I suspect this is not the issue , because the same code, the same pipeline, the same k8s is working absolutely fine in different namespace.

The above oracle issue is happening only when the pipeline try to deploy in default namespace.

I tried to telnet to the Oracle server, I get the response just it is that it is not able to connect from default namespace and I don't know why.

Also I have 2 Oracle database one in one prem and other in RDS, both have the same issue in default name space and it was able to connect with no issue from other namespace.

I don't know what is different in default namespace and what to check there.

Comment: You can create a test pod in namespaces and test the connection with curl, sqlplus ... to determine the issue ( some network policies block your traffic, wrong user/pass ...). Btw, the error mentioned to SID, I guess something wrong with your environment variables or configmap.

Comment: Hi Franxi , thanks for the reply , actually inside the pod i can able to curl,telnet and also i installed sqlplus and tried to connect to the db which is also working fine , the only problem is i get oracle issue when i do that from the deployment pipeline in the default namespace . the deployment is successful , when stating the profile it tried to connect to the oracle db which is where i have issue and that too only in default namespace .

Comment: I'm not sure what you need to check too, I don't know what is in your pipeline. I think you should add tag **oracle** and **jdbc**. Hope this help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18192521/ora-12505-tnslistener-does-not-currently-know-of-sid-given-in-connect-descript